# Converting linear map in polynomial space into matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb5HW.png) I am working on. I have part of the [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBSA4.png) for it:

```
T1 = t + 1
Tt = t + 2t + 3 = 3t + 3
Tt^2 = 2t^2 + 4t + 9
```

What is the process for obtaining these equations from the linear map? From the equations I can turn that into a matrix representation, but I'm unsure how they are obtained. Please be very specific as to what values are plugged in where. Also, in this context what is f(t)? No where is f defined so how am I to know what f(3) evaluates to? How is the value of f(3) different for T1 and Tt? Shouldn't it be constant as it doesn't depend on t at all?

Comment: How did you come up with these equations?

Comment: They were given to me by my professor.

Comment: The equations are obtained by applying $T$ to $1,t,t^2$ respectively. In other words, set $f(t)=1$ and apply $T$, then set $f(t)=t$ and apply $T$...

Comment: Yes I understand that but how is it applied to them? What is the process? Where is 1,t,t^2 plugged in? What does f(3) equal?

Comment: @alexR. I'm almost there but I still don't understand how to evaluate f(3)

Comment: @griest: yes that's correct

Comment: Yes thank you, I just got it the second before you posted your last comment, haha. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of $T$, $f$ is an arbitrary element of $P_2(\mathbb R)$, i.e., it’s some second-degree polynomial with real coefficients. To find a matrix for $T$, you first need to choose a basis for $P_2(\mathbb R)$, which your professor has done for you in those three equations, namely $\{1,t,t^2\}$. The three equations are obtained by plugging each of these polynomials in as $f$ in the formula for $(Tf)(t)$.

To take the third one as an example, $$\begin{align}
(Tf)(t)=(Tt^2)(t)&=t\cdot(t^2)'(t)+t\cdot (t^2)(2)+(t^2)(3) \\
&=t\cdot 2t+t\cdot2^2+3^2 \\
&=2t^2+4t+9.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes good example, I didn't understand that 1,t,t^2 are not the values you plug in for t, but it is the polynomial ITSELF. That is, for Tt, f(t) = t and for Tt^2, f(t) = t^2. Thank you, hopefully this will help other people with the same misunderstanding.